# When using turtle/tkinter in a remote instance of vscode, the window opens on the remote server's screen

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter, turtle-graphics, visual-studio-code-server

I do not think that this is a bug, but I think this is what is suppose to happen. I was expecting the window to run on the host computer but show on the client's screen.

I had a raspberry pi 4 with

```
from tkinter import * #import tkinter

root = Tk()

root.title("Simple gui!") # set frame title
root.geometry("200x100") # set frame size

root.mainloop() # show frame
```

saved as a .py (python) file. I set up a [vscode tunnel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.remote-server) then connected to it from a windows 10 PC. I ran the code from the PC but the tkinter window opened on the raspberry pi.

Does anyone know how to make this not happen and make the tkinter window open on the PC instead?

Thank you.

I believe that this also happens with turtle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.